# sharpdevelop Failed to load designer

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop, oxyplot

I'm using **Sharpdevelop 5.1.0.5134** with **.NET 4.5.51209**
to make desktop application based on **Windows.Forms**

At first, everything was fine, no warnings and the designer shows the form correctly and I can easily add components.

After that I added **OxyPlot** correctly from the **Package Management Console** and I found the new **PlotView** component in the **Custom Comonents** tab.

The problem is that I can't add the component to the Form from the tools tab, so I did it by writing the equivalents statements in the source file.

The building process went fine and the application worked fine, but now I can't see the Form in the designer tab and instead I got this message:

```
Failed to load designer. Check the source code for syntax errors and check if all references are available.

ICSharpCode.FormsDesigner.FormsDesignerLoadException: System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerException: Could not find type 'OxyPlot.WindowsForms.PlotView'.  Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced.  If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.

System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerException: The variable 'plot1' is either undeclared or was never assigned.
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.Error(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String exceptionText, String helpLink)
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)


   at ICSharpCode.FormsDesigner.FormsDesignerViewContent.LoadDesigner()
   at ICSharpCode.FormsDesigner.FormsDesignerViewContent.LoadAndDisplayDesigner()
   at ICSharpCode.FormsDesigner.FormsDesignerViewContent.LoadInternal(OpenedFile file, Stream stream)
   at ICSharpCode.SharpDevelop.Workbench.AbstractViewContentHandlingLoadErrors.Load(OpenedFile file, Stream stream)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: probably some dependencies within the default constructor of the form? remember that usually designers need to be able to create a form from scratch without additional context

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand. Actually I'm an electrical engineer and my knowledge in computer is limited, It would be desirable if you can simplify it to me

Comment: I actually missed part of the error. The fact that your code builds it doesnt mean its good :) There are still some things that can go wrong in the run time. One of them is binding libraries, and here it is your problem, the component you added needs OxyPlot.WindowsForms.PlotView class definition, which probably stays in OxyPlot library or sth like this. Just reference it to the project and it should work fine.

Comment: here is the project file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9shvGtKbyqxYWMtVjlyNTR0Rmc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry but I dont have time to debug your project, also I dont use sharpdevelop |(no idea why would one with VS Community available for free :) ) Reference the library and will be fine, otherwise just switch to VS and use nuget :P

Comment: how can I reference it ? aren't these directives and statements enough **using OxyPlot;**  .... **this.plot1 = new OxyPlot.WindowsForms.PlotView();**  .........  **private OxyPlot.WindowsForms.PlotView plot1;**

Comment: I used nuget to reference Oxyplot and I can see both **oxyplot.core** and **oxyplot.windowsforms** among the refernces

Comment: no, it's just enough for it to build, Visual Studio most likely wouldn't let you build it without proper references. You must look for something like: right click project, add reference/library
If you used nuget, then it should be enough, somehow it didnt worked, though. I cannot help much more/

Comment: Thanks @mikus . Anyway, I guess that I should continue adding components by writing their codes in the source files using copy/paste component templates

Comment: there is nothing wrong in not using designer, as long as you know what is your code doing :) if youre program works, and jsut designer doesnt, then it might be very much related to Sharpdevelop limitations.
Check if OXyPlot appears here, and try to add it if not:
http://allthelittlebits.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/SDImg17.jpg

Comment: no, it doesn't appear there !!!

Comment: so you need to add it manually, as shown on the picture (comes from SD tutorial :P). You can either download the library directly from the website, or take it from packages folder that nuget should created. You deifnitely have it somewhere if it builds and run :)

Comment: I will do it, thanks for helpful comments

Comment: was it the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug in SharpDevelop 5.1 being unable to resolve the OxyPlot assemblies.

It looks like SharpDevelop 4.4 does not have the same problem and can open the form in the designer.

As a workaround for SharpDevelop 5.1 you can copy the OxyPlot.dll and OxyPlot.WindowsForms.dll files into C:\Program Files (x86)\SharpDevelop\5.1\bin

Then restart SharpDevelop and then you can open the form in the designer without any errors.

This bug should be fixed in SharpDevelop 5.1.0.5173 and above.

Comment: perfect result; awsome